# Dynamically Controls

Tags: asp.net

I have dynamically generated a button an its event too.Now want to access a textbox (Generated Dynamically) into the onClick event of the Button.How can i do this?

Comment: 'How' is the button being generated? Are you coding it and then adding it to the page or is it being generated in a template control (i.e. GridView)?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it in class scope and use it in your button event handeler:

```
class MyClass
{
   TextBox txtBox = null;

   private void MyMethod()
   {
      var btn = new Button();
      btn.Click += MyBtnEventHandler
      ...
      txtBox = new TextBox();
   } 

   protected void MyBtnEventHandler(object sender, .....)
   {
       if(txtBox != null) var data = txtBox.Text;
   }
}
```

Comment: That's my problem. am not able to access txtBox in MyBtnEventHandler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding dynamic textbox the page using `Page.Controls.Add()` or `this.Controls.Add()` then did you try using `Page.FindControl(textBoxId)` in button's onClick event? You have to set the ID of dynamic textbox while adding it during runtime.